# Statically declared 2-D array C++ as data member of a class

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a `class grid` which contains the data members `unsigned NR`, `unsigned NC` and it should also contain a 2D array `double Coordiantes[NR][NC]`. I wish to initialize the data members `NR` and `NC` through the class constructor. I am trying to avoid the dynamic allocation of the 2-D array as I prefer contiguous memory allocation so as to avoid the cache misses as much as possible.

*I am not sure if it is possible but any inputs would be helpful.*

Comment: why not use std::vector instead?

Comment: I believe NR and NC must be known at compile time in order to create a static array like this. Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c?

Comment: `vector< vector<double> >` would solve the purpose, but I recently came to know accessing `vector< vector<double> > A` is quite slow as compared to `double A[m][n]`.

Comment: @DanielB.Thanks,  just what I needed.

Comment: It's not possible for c++...now...

Comment: @DanielB. That answer is syntactically correct, but is not idiomatic c++. Better use the RAII idiom.

Comment: True, the top answer there is not raii, but the less upvoted (go figure) answers are more in line with what probably ought to be done.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
class Array2D {
public:
    vector<int> v;
    int nc;
    Array2D(int NR, int NC) : v(NR*NC), nc(NC) {}
    int* operator[](int r) { return &v[r*nc]; }
};

int main()
{
    Array2D array2d(2, 3);
    array2d[0][0] = 1;
    array2d[1][2] = 6;
}
```

This allows you to create a class that will function like a 2D array. It's fast and the data is contiguous.

Comment: This is the cleanest implementation I've seen. Especially nice is the usage of the **built-in operator []** to access the contents without the need to implement it specifically for the second dimension.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername  - Thanks! Probably helped that I was originally a C programmer. I do love modern c++ though.

Comment: Interesting but somewhat risky - with `int*` there is no way to assert a validity of `a[i][j]` expression.

Comment: @Evg So true. I actually prefer the (r,c) approach and it's easy to bounds conditionally check, It's a minimalist approach with conventional brackets. Simplest thing i could think of. I currently use a ptr, row, and col. All consts in a constexpr class. An even smaller object footprint but very fast. And const correct thanks to c++20.

Comment: If you can stretch to C++20, returning a `std::span<int>` from the array operator would allow bounds checking. Not zero overhead though, since the extent is dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you simply use `std::vector<double>(NC*NR)`.
And index into it by `coord.at(i*NC + j)` (or `coord[i*NC + j]`, when you code is correct and you want to glean performance out of it).

You'll get contiguous memory and cache friendly loops without doing your own memory allocation. Always prefer RAII when possible.