# Convert malloc to new

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, new-operator

How to write the following code using new operator?
Please explain in detail.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include<alloc>
#define MAXROW 3
#define MAXCOL 5
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int (*p)[MAXCOL];
    p = (int(*)[MAXCOL])malloc(MAXROW*sizeof(*p));
}
```

Comment: Note that `<alloc>` is not a standard header. For `malloc`, use `<cstdlib>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, to answer the question literally:

```
p = new int[MAXROW][MAXCOL];
```

This allocates a 2D array (MAXROW by MAXCOL) on the free store and, as usual with `new`, returns a `int(*)[MAXCOL]` - the same type as decaying the 2D array. Don't forget to `delete[] p;`.

The last part brings up the importance of `std::vector`. Presumably, you know the size of the second dimension at compile-time. Therefore, a `std::vector<std::array<int, MAXCOL>>` would work with the added bonus of not requiring a `delete[]` statement, plus it knows its size (MAXROW). Please use this if at all possible.

In fact, in your example, both dimensions are known at compile-time, meaning a `std::array<std::array<int, MAXCOL>, MAXROW>` would also work here. That's typically preferable to dynamic allocation.

If neither dimension is known at compile-time, your best bet is usually a vector of vectors or a dedicated matrix class to increase performance when you know every inner vector is the same size.

Answer (score 1):

The literal question

> **”** How to write the following code using new operator?

… means something else than you think it means.

The ***`new` operator*** is a simple allocation function roughly directly analogous to C's `malloc`, except the C++ `new` operator is replacable by a user defined one.

You probably mean a ***`new` expression***. Such an expression invokes the `new` operator for allocation, *and* then invokes a constructor for initialization, if the allocated thing is of class type. And it's type safe.

Still, for your array you'd not want that either, but simply **`std::vector`** from the standard library.

---

Here's an example using a `std::vector` of vectors to create a matrix:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    int const n_rows = 3;
    int const n_cols = 5;

    using Row = vector<int>;

    vector<Row> v( n_rows, Row( n_cols ) );

    // E.g. v[1] is a row, and v[1][2] is an int item in that row.
}
```

---

Even if you don't so often use matrices, it can be a good idea to wrap the general notion of a matrix, in a class. A simple way is to use a single `std::vector` for storage, and provide e.g. an `at` function or an `operator()` for indexing from client code. If you don't yet feel like doing this yourself, then e.g. the Boost library provides a matrix class.

Comment: Generally, I avoid using nested vectors for N-dim array like objects. There are multiple indirections to access an element which slows things down..

Comment: @doug: I agree. That's why I recommended using a single vector as matrix storage. The simple declaration is the reason for the nested one. (In passing I find it amazing that nobody commented on the obvious typo. Fixed. :) )

Comment: There's a very simple way to use a single vector and still use the semantics of a 2D built in array. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123452/statically-declared-2-d-array-c-as-data-member-of-a-class/36123944#36123944)

Comment: @doug: Yes, that's the basic class sketched at the end of this answer. I recommend not using all uppercase identifiers. All uppercase identifiers can easily collide with macros (it's a common convention to reserve these identifiers for macros).

Comment: @doug: More subjectively, I would not return a row pointer, because it exposes the internal implementation. E.g. it makes it difficult to let the same client code work with a view such as a transposed matrix. Instead just let `operator()` take two arguments, and return reference to item.

Comment: Yes, I too prefer operator() but for updating older code based on [][] it models built in arrays closely. But, as you point out, it's not very easily modified for views such as transpose.  I find I rarely even use new and delete these days. Modern C++ is such a pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is C++ I will recomend using `std::array` and `std::unique_ptr`
Also when using `malloc` you should use `free` un-alloc or free the memory, if you use `new` you need to use `delete`; if you `new[]` you need to use `delete[]`

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <array>
#define MAXROW 3
#define MAXCOL 5
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int (*p)[MAXCOL];
    p = (int(*)[MAXCOL])malloc(MAXROW*sizeof(*p));
    free(p); //free memory 
    array<int,MAXCOL> *p1 = new array<int,MAXCOL>[MAXROW];
    delete []p1; //use this to delete the variable
    array<array<int,MAXCOL>,MAXROW> *p2 = new array<array<int,MAXCOL>,MAXROW>;
    delete p2;  // normal delete for this one
    auto p3 = make_unique<array<array<int,MAXCOL>,MAXROW>>();
    //no delete needed for p3, it is a smart pointer.
}
```