# Why does this need auto?

Tags: c++, auto

```
auto data = new char[480][640][3]();
char data = new char[480][640][3]();
```

First works.
Second doesnt.
Why? Isn't auto supposed to just replace itself with the type of the initializer?

Comment: Because `char` is not a pointer type. You don't need `auto` but you need a correct type. `new` returns a pointer.

Comment: and if you are going multi-dimensional array mad - use a library. life will be a lot easier.

Comment: I'm using this to store the image to display via OpenGL. Don't think a library's a good idea here.

Comment: @Moterius Refer to a [good beginners book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) before asking trivia basics like this here please. That's definitely and explicitly unwanted.

Comment: 3 D arrays are annoying. You can make [a really simple and safe 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301) out of a `vector` with the same syntax as a regular array, but to get the third dimension you have to start jumping through hoops with proxies or give up on `[]` and [use `operator ()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301).

Comment: Well this array is basically a screen buffer anyways [x][y][0|1|2] = [r|g|b], so I doubt that's necessary.

Comment: You could make a 2D array of 1D arrays. That simplifies things a little.

Comment: `auto` is never *necessary*.   It is a shortcut for convenience when the programmer can't (or doesn't want to expend the effort to) work out and explicitly code the actual type.  In templates, it can simplify code a lot, but is still not necessary.   In this case, the type of `data` needs to be `char(*)[640][3]`, not `char`.

Comment: `struct Display { std::byte buffer[480][640][3]{}; };` and `Display* display = new Display;`  Also a convenient place to add member functions that operate on a display.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the type isn't `char`. The type is `char(*)[640][3]` and the declaration would be written as

```
char (*data)[640][3] = new char[480][640][3]();
```

Comment: And as pointed out above, 'new' returns a pointer instead of the actual object, meaning it wont cause the damn stackoverflow error that led me here in the first place. Makes sense now.