# Incorrect subtraction of different type pointers in c++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, c++17

I need to implement a custom class `FlattenedVector<T>` which accepts a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` object as input and simulates working with it, as the `std::vector<T>` type comes true.

I need to implement it using iterators and use not more than 40 bytes of memory, so I'm using pointers everywhere.

Further more, for fast time of accessing an arbitrary element, it is proposed to have a vector of prefix sums of the sizes of subvectors of the input vector (`ll* pref`).

I've got a `FlattenedVector` class:

```
template <typename T>
class FlattenedVector {
    friend class FlattenedVectorIterator<T>;
    using OutIterator = typename vector<vector<T>>::iterator;
    using InIterator = typename vector<T>::iterator;

private:

    vector<vector<T>> * arr;
    ll* pref;
    
public:

    FlattenedVector(vector<vector<T>> &vec_in) : arr(&vec_in) {
        pref = generate_prefix(*arr);
    }

    FlattenedVectorIterator<T> begin() {
        return FlattenedVectorIterator<T>(arr -> begin(), arr -> begin() -> begin(), arr -> begin(), pref);
    }

    FlattenedVectorIterator<T> end() {
        auto x = arr -> end();
        InIterator* new_ptr_inIt = reinterpret_cast<InIterator*>(&x);
        return FlattenedVectorIterator<T>(arr -> end(),  *(new_ptr_inIt), arr -> begin(), pref);
    }

};
```

And a `FlattenedVectorIterator` class, with all functions for random access iterators are overloaded.

```
template <typename T>
class FlattenedVectorIterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>{
    
public:
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using OutIterator = typename vector<vector<T>>::iterator;
    using InIterator = typename vector<T>::iterator;

    FlattenedVectorIterator(OutIterator outIt_, InIterator inIt_, OutIterator outBegin_, ll* prefIt_)
    {
        outIt = outIt_;// outIt will iterate over std::vector<std::vector<T>>
            inIt = inIt_;//inIt will iterator in std::vector<T>
        outBegin = outBegin_;//iterator to the beginig of the std::vector<T>

        prefIt = prefIt_;//pointer to the array of prefix sums.
    }   
/*
all basic operators overloaded
*/
```

The problem is in the implementation of difference between two iterators:

```
size_t operator-(const FlattenedVectorIterator& other) const{

    int global_position_this = get_global_position(*this, prefIt);
    int global_position_other = get_global_position(other, prefIt);

    return global_position_other - global_position_this;        
}
```

and

```
int get_global_position(const FlattenedVectorIterator<T>& it, ll* pref) const{
        
    int current_subarray = it.outIt - it.outBegin ;
    int elements_before_current_subarray = 0;
    if(current_subarray != 0){

        //+1 because in prefIt[0] i have size of the whole Flattened vector,
        // and prefIt[1] = 0

        elements_before_current_subarray = prefIt[current_subarray + 1];
    }

    //outIt points to the 0'th element in current array, so 
    // I want to cast it's address to InIterator type

    const InIterator* current_subarray_begin = reinterpret_cast<const InIterator*>(&(it.outIt));

    // the problem is here, while i'm trying to get local position of 
    //the first element it does n't give me zero but any other integer.

    int current_local_position = it.inIt - (*current_subarray_begin);
    int current_global_position = elements_before_current_subarray + current_local_position;
    return current_global_position;
}
```

I've tried to look for the addresses `it.inIt` and `current_subarray_begin`

```
cout << &(it.outIt) << " " <<current_subarray_begin;
```

and they're the same for the zero's element, but

```
it.inIt - (*current_subarray_begin)
```

is still not 0.

Comment: Still working through what you're up to here, but [why not actually flatten the `vector`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301)?

Comment: I can't use vector<T> in my class, i' ve got only 40 bytes in FlattenedVector, and 32 bytes max in FlattenedVectorIterator , so 4 pointers is my max.

Comment: I do not understand that statement. The `vector` of `vector`s approach you're using is soaking far more resources than a single large `vector`

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<const InIterator*>(&(it.outIt))` won't do what you hope... `outIt` is an iterator into the outer `vector<vector<T>>` - in most implementations a `vector<T>*`.  It doesn't point to the first `T` in that inner vector, it points to the vector management object, which has a few pointers (begin, end, capacity) off to the inner vector.  Hint: don't use reinterpret_cast until you're really familiar with C++ - you're hiding bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making your life much harder than it should be...  As a rule of thumb, pointers to iterators are something to avoid.

The first problem that you have, is that you have to keep track of 2 iterators: one for the index lookup table, and one to the actual data.  Using an index, you'd avoid any potential mishap, and save (a little) space by removing one redundancy.  Your iterators would then look somewhat like this:

```
template <typename T>
class FlattenedArray {
   //...
   public:
    // the iterator is SO specialized, its declaration really belongs here.
    class iterator {
        friend class FlattenedArray<T>;

        // ...
      private:
        iterator(FlattenedArray<T>* parent, size_t pos)
            : parent_(parent),
              outer_index_(parent->get_outer_vector_index(pos)),
              pos_(pos) {}

        // dereferencing.
      public:
        T& operator*() {
            assert(parent_);
            assert(*this != parent_->end());
            size_t inner_index =
                pos_ - (parent_->lut_.at(outer_index_) -
                        parent_->two_d_array_.at(outer_index_).size());
            return parent_->two_d_array_.at(outer_index_).at(inner_index);
        }

        //...

       private:
        FlattenedArray<T>* parent_;
        size_t outer_index_;  // index into the indices lookup table
        size_t pos_;          // flat position
    };

    frienc class iterator;
    // ...
};
```

With the look up table computed like this:

```
void FlattenedArrayT>::compute_lookup_table() {
    std::vector<size_t> lut;
    lut.reserve(two_d_array_.size());

    size_t sum = 0;
    for (const auto& ar : two_d_array_) lut.push_back(sum += ar.size());

    std::swap(lut_,
              lut);  // using swap (or move), because it will not throw.
}
```

So that you can use a plain binary search for quick random access:

```
size_t FlattenedArrayT>::get_outer_vector_index(size_t pos) const {
    std::vector<size_t>::const_iterator it =
        std::upper_bound(lut_.cbegin(), lut_.cend(), pos);
    return it - lut_.begin();
}
```

Working with indices will make everything much simpler to reason about and will be much safer and run as quickly than working with pointers to iterators .

Here is a quick and dirty working prototype of this concept, make sure that assertions are matched by exception throwing, etc...

You can also try and play with it directly on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/4aToMxnrd

NOTE: this prototype does not handle empty subarrays, but this feature shoudl be rather trivial to add.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class FlattenedArray {
   public:
    class iterator {
        friend class FlattenedArray<T>;

       private:
        iterator(FlattenedArray<T>* parent, size_t pos)
            : parent_(parent),
              outer_index_(parent->get_outer_vector_index(pos)),
              pos_(pos) {}

        // dereferencing.
       public:
        T& operator*() {
            assert(parent_);
            assert(*this != parent_->end());
            size_t inner_index =
                pos_ - (parent_->lut_.at(outer_index_) -
                        parent_->two_d_array_.at(outer_index_).size());
            return parent_->two_d_array_.at(outer_index_).at(inner_index);
        }

        // the usual stuff...
       public:
        iterator() = default;
        iterator(const iterator&) = default;
        iterator(iterator&&) = default;
        iterator& operator=(const iterator&) = default;
        iterator& operator=(iterator&&) = default;

        friend bool operator==(const iterator& x, const iterator& y) {
            assert(x.parent_ == y.parent_);
            return x.pos_ == y.pos_;
        }

        friend bool operator!=(const iterator& x, const iterator& y) {
            return !(x == y);
        }

        // iterator operations
        //
        //  Since ++ and -- are the most common oprrations, computation of inner
        //  index is optimized
        //

        iterator& operator++() {
            assert(parent_);
            assert(*this != parent_->end());

            if (*this != parent_->end()) {
                ++pos_;
                if (pos_ >= parent_->lut_[outer_index_]) ++outer_index_;
                if (outer_index_ < parent_->lut_.size()) *this = parent_->end();
            }
            return *this;
        }

        iterator operator++(int) {  // postfix operator
            iterator result = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return result;
        }

        iterator& operator--() {
            assert(parent_);
            assert(*this != parent_->begin());

            if (*this == parent_->end() && !parent_->empty()) {
                pos_ = parent_->size() - 1;
                outer_index_ = get_outer_vector_index(pos_);
            } else {
                --pos_;
                if (pos_ < parent_->lut[outer_index_] -
                               parent_->two_d_array[outer_index_].size())
                    --outer_index_;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        iterator operator--(int) {  // postfix operator
            iterator result = *this;
            --(*this);
            return result;
        }

        //  These cannot be optimized

        friend iterator operator+(const iterator& x, size_t n) {
            assert(x.parent_ && (x.pos_ + n) <= x.parent_->size());

            iterator r = x;

            if (n == 0) return r;

            if (r.pos_ + n >= r.parent_->size()) {
                r.outer_index_ = r.parent_->lut_.size();
                r.pos_ = r.parent_->size();
            } else {
                r.pos_ += n;
                while (r.outer_index_ < r.parent_->lut_.size() &&
                       r.parent_->lut_[r.outer_index_] < r.pos_) {
                    ++r.outer_index_;
                }
            }
            return r;
        }

        friend iterator operator-(iterator& x, size_t n) {
            assert(x.parent_);
            assert(n <= x.pos_);

            iterator r = x;

            if (n == 0) return x;

            r.pos_ -= n;
            while (r.outer_index_ != 0 &&
                   r.parent_->lut_[r.outer_index_] < r.pos_) {
                --r.outer_index_;
            }
            return r;
        }

        // the difference function this question was about.
        friend ptrdiff_t operator-(const iterator& x, const iterator& y) {
            assert(x->parent_ && &(x->parent_) == &(y.parent_));
            return x->pos_ - y->pos_;
        }

       private:
        FlattenedArray<T>* parent_;
        size_t outer_index_;  // index into the indices lookup table
        size_t pos_;          // flat position
    };

    friend class iterator;

   public:
    FlattenedArray(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& ar) : two_d_array_(ar) {
        compute_lookup_table();
    }

    void compute_lookup_table() {
        std::vector<size_t> lut;
        lut.reserve(two_d_array_.size());

        size_t sum = 0;
        for (const auto& ar : two_d_array_) lut.push_back(sum += ar.size());

        std::swap(lut_,
                  lut);  // using swap (or move), because it will not throw.
    }

    bool empty() const { return two_d_array_.empty(); }

    size_t size() const {
        if (empty()) return 0;
        return lut_.back();
    }

    iterator begin()  { return iterator{this, 0}; }

    iterator end()  { return iterator{this, size()}; }

    T& at(size_t pos) {
        size_t outer = get_outer_vector_index(pos);
        size_t inner_pos =
            pos - (lut_.at(outer) - two_d_array_.at(outer).size());
        return two_d_array_.at(outer).at(inner_pos);
    }

    const T& at(size_t pos) const {
        size_t outer = get_outer_vector_index(pos);
        size_t inner_pos =
            pos - (lut_.at(outer) - two_d_array_.at(outer).size());
        return two_d_array_.at(outer).at(inner_pos);
    }

    T& operator[](size_t pos) { return at(pos); }

    const T& operator[](size_t pos) const { return at(pos); }

   private:
    size_t get_outer_vector_index(size_t pos) const {
        std::vector<size_t>::const_iterator it =
            std::upper_bound(lut_.cbegin(), lut_.cend(), pos);
        return it - lut_.begin();
    }

   private:
   public: // for testing.
    std::vector<std::vector<T>>& two_d_array_;  // array being flattened
    std::vector<size_t> lut_;                   // index look up table
};

int main() {
    // generate a vector with incrementing values for testing

    int N = 1000;          // minumum number of elements in vector.
    int MIN_VECTORS = 10;  // minmum vectors wanted.

    std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> two_d_array;

    size_t total = 0;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < N;) {
        // create random sized_vector,
        // we'd like at least 10 vectors in array[].
        std::vector<size_t> inner(rand() % (N / 10));
        for (size_t j = 0; j < inner.size(); ++j, ++n) inner[j] = n;
        total += inner.size();
        two_d_array.push_back(inner);
    }

    std::cout << "outer size = " << two_d_array.size()
              << ", total size: " << total << "\n";

    std::cout << "sizes :";
    for (auto& a : two_d_array) std::cout << " " << a.size();
    std::cout << "\n";

    // test with no iterators
    FlattenedArray<size_t> flat(two_d_array);

    std::cout << "lut :";
    for (auto& el : flat.lut_) std::cout << " " << el;
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "flat.size(): " << flat.size() << "\n";


    std::cout << "testing random access...\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < flat.size(); ++i) {
        try {
            if (flat[i] != i) {
                std::cerr << "error: flat[i] = " << flat[i]
                          << ", expected: " << i << "\n";
                return 3;
            }
        } catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << "error at index: " << i << ", error: " << e.what()
                      << "\n";
            return 36;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "OK.\n\n";

    std::cout << "testing sequential access through iterator...\n";
    int n = 0;
    for (auto i = flat.begin(); i != flat.end(); ++i, ++n) {
        try {
            if (*i != n) {
                std::cerr << "error: *i = " << *i << ", expected: " << n
                          << "\n";
                return 3;
            }
        } catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << "error at index: " << n << ", error: " << e.what()
                      << "\n";
            return 36;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "OK.\n\n";

    std::cout << "All tests were successful!\n";
    return 0;
}
```