# dynamically allocate matrix using build-in vector library

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, global, allocation

I am facing problem in allocating matrix using vector library globally.
However, in my code, I am allocating vector as an array, which you can see below.

```
matrix = new double*[row*col];

for (int i = 0; i < row*col; i++){
    Matrix[i] = new double[col];
}
```

Please suggest a possible way to allocate matrix globally (preferably using build-in vector or user classes)

```
matrix = new double*[row*col];

for (int i = 0; i < row*col; i++){
    Matrix[i] = new double[col];
}
```

Comment: You're creating a matrix with `row*col` rows, and `col` columns. Is that really what you're supposed to do?

Comment: I am creating matrix using array format, like in for loop it allocate memory of matrix using array size as a vector..
But, I am looking for the way to allocate matrix using build-in vector i.e. std::vector

Comment: [Take a look at this trick posted by doug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301). Resizing the `vector` is more difficult, you have to do all of the copying yourself, but the performance improvements from contiguous memory are usually worth it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Initialize Vector Of Vectors in C++](/q/31200535/90527)", "[Arrays vs Vector of Vectors when creating matrices - what is the most practical option?](/q/62837573/90527)"

Answer (score 2):

You may use `std::vector`like below:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix(ROW_COUNT, std::vector<double>(COLUMN_COUNT));
```

Resizing can be done like this:

```
matrix.resize(new_rows);
for (int i = 0; i < new_rows; ++i)
    matrix[i].resize(new_cols);
```

Comment: Resizing the matrix will not work like this, as only newly created rows will have the correct column count.

Comment: @DrPepperJo. You are right. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you,
it worked.
Now, I want to allocate in header file and outside the main function, so that I won't call matrix in each function.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would declare matrix as a flat vector:

```
double matrix[row*col];
```

But if you want to do it with STL container, I would use @Armin-Montigny sugested:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix;
```

Of course you could do it as a separate Matrix class, that encapsulates std::vector.