# Getting "Buffer overrun" warnings while allocating memory to a 2d array in a copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, compiler-warnings, copy-constructor

I am creating a pacman game in Visual Studio 2022 with C++. For this game I have a Class "Map" to load the map from a text file and render it. I save the data from the textfile in `int** map` in my Map class. I now need this data for other objects in my game. So I was trying to make a copy constructor for it.

My copy constructor `Map(const Map& original)` works fine I guess. It copies the data to the new object and allocates memory to a new pointer and then copies the values in it without crashing or causing an error. But I still get these warnings:

- Warning C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'map'.
- Warning C6385: Reading invalid data from 'map'.
- Warning C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'map[y]'.

Here a simplified version:

**Map.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>

class Map
{
public:
    // members would be private, only public for easier testing
    int height = 0, width = 0;
    int** map = nullptr;

    Map();
    Map(const Map& original);
    ~Map();
};
```

**Map.cpp:**

```
#include "Map.h"

Map::Map()
{
    // set map size
    height = 3;
    width = 2;

    // dynamically allocating memory for int** map
    map = (int**)malloc(height * sizeof(int*));
    if (!map)
        exit(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        map[i] = (int*)malloc(width * sizeof(int));

    // giving map some values
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        if (!map[y])
            exit(1);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            map[y][x] = x + y;
    }
}

Map::Map(const Map& original)
{
    // copy map size
    height = original.height;
    width = original.width;

    // allocate new memory for the new map
    map = (int**)malloc(height * sizeof(int*));
    if (!map)
        exit(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        map[i] = (int*)malloc(width * sizeof(int));     // Warning C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'map'.

    // copy the values from original.map to this->map
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        if (!map[y])        // Warning C6385: Reading invalid data from 'map'.
            exit(2);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            map[y][x] = original.map[y][x];     // Warning C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'map[y]'.
    }
}

Map::~Map()
{
    // freeing allocated memory
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        free(map[i]);
    free(map);
}
```

I only get these warnings in the copy construcor but not in the constructor, but I have basically written the same stuff in both of them.
I am now wondering if I should just ignore these warnings or if I have done something wrong.

I also tried doing the same thing with `new` / `delete` instead of `malloc()` / `free()` and it worked aswell but I did not get any warnings there.

Comment: Code analysis warnings are notoriously unreliable.  Project > Properties > Code Analysis > General > "Enable Microsoft Code Analysis" = No and it will stop complaining.  Do favor new[] in C++ code.

Comment: I'd rather use the rule of zero and `std::vector`

Comment: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6386?view=msvc-170) suggests that the full message contains more info and is something along the line of "Buffer overrun: accessing 'buffer name', the writable size is 'size1' bytes, but 'size2' bytes may be written: Lines: x, y". Did you include the complete messages?

Comment: [Good, safe, self-managed, and simple rectangular array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301)