# C6386 warning in VS 22 buffer overrun

Tags: c

I am trying to make a function that gets a matrix and shifts its columns to the right or left, depend on the user's repeat input. While doing this, I noticed compiler warnings (C6386, C6001, C6385), all in the same code area, and I can't find the problem.

Warning C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'temp_row'.
Warning C6001   Using uninitialized memory '*temp_row'.
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'temp_row'.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_MATRIX_ALLOWED 2
#define MAX_COMMEND_LINE 81
#define MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN 13

int matrix_count = 0;
char variebels_names[MAX_MATRIX_ALLOWED][MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN];
int* matrix_data[MAX_MATRIX_ALLOWED];
int matrix_rows[MAX_MATRIX_ALLOWED];
int matrix_cols[MAX_MATRIX_ALLOWED];

float StringToFloat(const char* str) {
    float result = 0.0;
    sscanf_s(str, "%f", &result);
    return result;
}

void createMatrix(const char* name, float rows, float cols) {
    // check name length and letters
    if (strlen(name) > MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN) {
        printf_s("Error: '%s' - invalid variable name!\n", name);
        return;
    }
    // check if name is already in use
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix_count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(name, variebels_names[i]) == 0) {
            printf_s("Error: variable name '%s' is already in use!\n", name);
            return;
        }
    }
    // check if the rows and cols are int
    if (rows - (int)rows != 0 || cols - (int)cols != 0 || cols <= 0 || rows <= 0) {
        printf_s("Error: invalid dimension!\n");
        return;
    }
    int cols_int = (int)cols;
    int rows_int = (int)rows;
    // check if there is the same variable name
    if (matrix_count >= MAX_MATRIX_ALLOWED) {
        printf_s("Error: zeros cannot save more than 2 variables!\n");
        return;
    }

    /*save memory for the matrix data*/

    int** matrix = (int**)malloc (rows_int *sizeof(int*));
    if (!matrix) exit(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows_int; i++)
    {
       matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(cols_int * sizeof(int));
       if (!matrix[i]) exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows_int; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols_int; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    matrix_data[matrix_count] = matrix;
    matrix_rows[matrix_count] = rows_int;
    matrix_cols[matrix_count] = cols_int;
    strncpy_s(variebels_names[matrix_count], MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN, name, MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN - 1);
    variebels_names[matrix_count][MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN - 1] = '\0';

    matrix_count++;
    fflush(stdout);
}

void matrixShift(const char* name, int repeat) {
    //check if name is defined
    int matrix_index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, variebels_names[i]) == 0)
        {
            matrix_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (matrix_index == -1)
    {
        printf_s("Error: '%s' - unknown variable!\n", name);
        return;
    }
    int rows = matrix_rows[matrix_index];
    int cols = matrix_cols[matrix_index];
    int** matrix = matrix_data[matrix_index];
    int shift = repeat % cols;
    if (shift >= 0) {
        shift = (cols - (repeat % cols)) % cols;
    }
    else
    {
        shift = (-repeat) % cols;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        // Create a temporary row
        int* temp_row = (int*)malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
        if (!temp_row) exit(1);
        int temp_index = 0;

        // Copy elements from the original row to the temporary row
        for (int j = shift; j < cols; j++) {
            temp_row[temp_index] = matrix[i][j];
            temp_index++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < shift; j++) {
            temp_row[temp_index] = matrix[i][j];
            temp_index++;
        }

        // Copy elements back to the original row
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = temp_row[j];
        }

        // Free the temporary row
        free(temp_row);
    }
}

int main() {
    char command[MAX_COMMEND_LINE];
    printf_s("$ ");
    fflush(stdout);
    while (fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        char* token;
        char* context = NULL;
        // split the command string
        token = strtok_s(command, " \n", &context);
        // check if the user didn't put input well
        if (token == NULL) {
            printf_s("$ ");
            fflush(stdout);
            continue;
        }
        // compare the tokens to the commands
        if (strcmp(token, "exit") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(token, "zeros") == 0) {
            token = strtok_s(NULL, " \n", &context);
            if (token == NULL) {
                printf_s("Error: illegal command!\n");
                printf_s("$ ");
                fflush(stdout);
                continue;
            }
            char variable_name[MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN];
            strncpy_s(variable_name, MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN, token, MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN - 1);
            variable_name[MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN - 1] = '\0';
            // checking the length of the variable name
            if (strlen(variable_name) > MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN) {
                printf_s("Error: '%s' - invalid variable name!\n", variable_name);
                printf_s("$ ");
                fflush(stdout);
                continue;
            }

            token = strtok_s(NULL, " \n", &context);
            if (token == NULL) {
                printf_s("Error: illegal command!\n");
                printf_s("$ ");
                fflush(stdout);
                continue;
            }
            float rows = StringToFloat(token);

            token = strtok_s(NULL, " \n", &context);
            if (token == NULL) {
                printf_s("Error: illegal command!\n");
                printf_s("$ ");
                fflush(stdout);
                continue;
            }
            float cols = StringToFloat(token);

            createMatrix(variable_name, rows, cols);
        }
        else if (strcmp(token, "shift") == 0) {
            token = strtok_s(NULL, " \n", &context);
            if (token == NULL) {
                printf_s("Error: illegal command!\n");
                printf_s("$ ");
                fflush(stdout);
                continue;
            }
            char variable_name[MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN];
            strncpy_s(variable_name, MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN, token, MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN - 1);
            variable_name[MAX_MATRIX_NAME_LEN - 1] = '\0';

            token = strtok_s(NULL, " \n", &context);
            if (token == NULL) {
                printf_s("Error: illegal command!\n");
                printf_s("$ ");
                fflush(stdout);
                continue;
            }
            int repeat = StringToFloat(token);
            matrixShift(variable_name, repeat);
        }
        else {
            printf_s("Error: unknown command!\n");
        }
        printf_s("$ ");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    // free allocated memory for matrices
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix_count; i++) {
        free(matrix_data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to solve it using `-1` from the `temp_row` size but it didn't work.

Comment: @omer The code does not make sense because there are used undeclared variables. Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: how can i do that? all the code is 300 rows

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i made it now more minimal

Comment: @tomer I do not see a program.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74815627/getting-buffer-overrun-warnings-while-allocating-memory-to-a-2d-array-in-a-cop) (althought this is c++).

Comment: "Reproducible" is the criteria that is held inviolable, as you approach "Minimal". Your example is not reproducible, since it cannot be compiled and run. There is no `main()`. There are no includes. There is no `matrix_` anything. There is no `repeat`.

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly in what you did not include in your question. What, exactly, is `matrix_data[matrix_index]`? If that is simply `rows * cols` integers sequentially in memory, then that is why your code crashes. `int** matrix` needs to be a list of _pointers_, each of which points to a row.

Comment: i made an edit to the post.. the code contains now all my parts that relevant

Comment: In addition to the edit I made to your question to add a missing brace, to get it compile without warnings, you need `int** matrix_data[MAX_MATRIX_ALLOWED];`, instead of `int* matrix_data[MAX_MATRIX_ALLOWED];`.

Comment: Fisrt of all thank you all!!! the progrem is running all the time but it always show the warning that i mentioned. and the lines that shows the problem are the lines inside the FOR loops of the shiftmatrix function. (the temp_row[temp_index] lines.

Comment: @MarkAdler The "input" is the source code - the warnings are from MSVC's static code analysis.

Comment: To the asker: Please make the (important) change in your code that Mark has mentioned (i.e. changing the `int* matrix_data..` to `int** matrix_data...`). I edited your question a bit (minor grammatical stuff) but it's serverely frowned-upon for 3rd-party editors to change **code** in questions.

Comment: Then I have been severely frowned upon, since I added a missing brace.

Comment: @Mark - That was a 'trivial' edit, correcting a likely typo. Changing a variable type is a bit more hefty (I notice that you didn't do it). :)

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous posts on Stack Overflow about "false positive" C6386 warnings from the Visual Studio (MSVC) compiler. This is a 'weakness' in the static analyser (I don't like to use the term, "bug," because static analysis is a highly complex process and the compiler can't always see all possible outcomes of code execution, even though you – as the author – may *know* that certain conditions can't occur).

However, despite the numerous *closely related* posts, I can't find one that proposes a workaround for your particular issue, so I shall offer a possibility.

But first, some attempts at explaining the warnings:

1. > warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory '*temp_row'
   > warning C6385: Reading invalid data from 'temp_row'.

When the analyser sees the last of the three nested `for (int j = 0 ...)` loops, it can't be 100% sure that the previous two loops have actually written to all elements of the `temp_row` array (even though you know they have). You can silence these by using `calloc` instead of `malloc`, which will initialize all elements to zero.

2. > warning C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'temp_row'.

In this case, the analyser isn't aware that the `temp_index` value is *guaranteed* to be in the `[0..cols)` range (again, even though you know it will be). You can silence this warning by adding an additional check (that `temp_index < cols`) in the second of your inner `for (int j = 0 ...)` loops.

Here is the relevant section of your code with these changes made (I have left your original code lines but commented them out):

```c
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        // Create a temporary row
        int* temp_row = calloc(cols, sizeof(int)); 
    //  int* temp_row = (int*)malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
        if (!temp_row) exit(1);
        int temp_index = 0;

        // Copy elements from the original row to the temporary row
        for (int j = shift; j < cols; j++) {
            temp_row[temp_index] = matrix[i][j];
            temp_index++;
        }
    //  for (int j = 0; j < shift; j++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < shift && temp_index < cols; j++) {
            temp_row[temp_index] = matrix[i][j];
            temp_index++;
        }

        // Copy elements back to the original row
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = temp_row[j];
        }

        // Free the temporary row
        free(temp_row);
    }
```

Making these changes silences all three warnings on my version of MSVC (Visual Studio 2022). However, they also cause me some confusion, because keeping only the *first* change (i.e. using `calloc`) removes the C6383 and C6385 but leaves the C6001; further, keeping only the *second* change removes the C6001. This is the *exact opposite* of what I was expecting!