# Why is my Cellular Automata implementation broken?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, procedural-generation, procedural-programming

I've been messing around with procedural noise lately, and decided to give a fresh stab at relearning Cellular Automata to generate cave-like maps. But I'm not sure if my implementation of 2D arrays is malformed, or if it's something in my CA implementation which is causing problems...

In `GenerateCA`, if you print the `temp` array right after copying the `grid` array, it's contents appear identical. But after even a single iteration through checking neighbors, all cells become `DEAD`. What's going on here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

#define UCHAR unsigned char
const UCHAR DEAD = 0;
const UCHAR ALIVE = 1;
const uint32_t MAPSIZE_X = 20;
const uint32_t MAPSIZE_Y = 8;
const uint8_t NOISEDENSITY = 80;
const uint32_t ITERATIONS = 3;

// Creates a new array
template <typename T>
T** AllocateArray2D(uint32_t size_x, uint32_t size_y) {
    T** arr = new UCHAR*[size_x];
    for (auto i = 0; i < size_x; i++)
        arr[i] = new T[size_y];
    return arr;
}

// Creates a shallow copy of an existing array
template <typename T>
T** CopyArray2D(T** arrSource, uint32_t size_x, uint32_t size_y) {
    auto arr = AllocateArray2D<T>(size_x, size_y);
    for(auto y = 0; y < size_y; y++) {
        for(auto x = 0; x < size_x; x++) {
            arr[x][y] = arrSource[x][y];
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

// Prints the cell state of each element of the array
template <typename T>
void PrintArray2D(T** arr, uint32_t size_x, uint32_t size_y, bool bAddHorizontalRule = true) {
    for(auto y = 0; y < size_y; y++) {
        for(auto x = 0; x < size_x; x++) {
            std::cout << (arr[x][y] == DEAD ? " " : "#");
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    if(bAddHorizontalRule) {
        for(auto x = 0; x < size_x; x++) {
            std::cout << "=";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

// Frees an array from memory
template <typename T>
void FreeArray2D(T** arr, uint32_t size_x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size_x; i++) {
        delete[] arr[i];
        arr[i] = nullptr;
    }
    delete[] arr;
    arr = nullptr;
}

// Creates a random grid of dead/alive cells based on a threshold between 1-100
UCHAR** GenerateGrid(uint32_t size_x, uint32_t size_y, uint32_t noiseDensity = 50) {
    auto grid = AllocateArray2D<UCHAR>(MAPSIZE_X, MAPSIZE_Y);
    
    for(auto y = 0; y < MAPSIZE_Y; y++) {
        for(auto x = 0; x < MAPSIZE_X; x++) {
            auto density = rand() % 100 + 1;
            if(density < noiseDensity)
                grid[x][y] = ALIVE;
            else
                grid[x][y] = DEAD;
        }
    }
    
    PrintArray2D<UCHAR>(grid, MAPSIZE_X, MAPSIZE_Y);
    return grid;
}

// Returns the number of neighboring cells (from [x, y]) which are alive
uint32_t get_neighbor_count(UCHAR** grid, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    uint32_t count = 0;
    for(auto yy = y - 1; yy <= y + 1; yy++) {
        for(auto xx = x - 1; xx <= x + 1; xx++) {
            if(yy > -1 && yy < MAPSIZE_Y && xx > -1 && xx < MAPSIZE_X) {
                if (yy != y || xx != x) {
                    if(grid[xx][yy] == ALIVE)
                        count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

// Performs Cellular Automata based on an existing grid, returning a new grid
UCHAR** GenerateCA(UCHAR** grid, uint32_t iterations, uint8_t neighborThreshold = 4) {
    auto temp = CopyArray2D<UCHAR>(grid, MAPSIZE_X, MAPSIZE_Y);
    
    for(auto it = 0; it < iterations; it++) {
        for(auto y = 0; y < MAPSIZE_Y; y++) {
            for(auto x = 0; x < MAPSIZE_X; x++) {
                auto neighborCount = get_neighbor_count(temp, x, y);
                if (neighborCount >= neighborThreshold)
                    temp[x][y] = ALIVE;
                else
                    temp[x][y] = DEAD;
            }
        }
        PrintArray2D<UCHAR>(temp, MAPSIZE_X, MAPSIZE_Y);
    }

    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    auto grid = GenerateGrid(MAPSIZE_X, MAPSIZE_Y, NOISEDENSITY);
    auto grid_ca = GenerateCA(grid, ITERATIONS);

    FreeArray2D<UCHAR>(grid_ca, MAPSIZE_X);
    FreeArray2D<UCHAR>(grid, MAPSIZE_X);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Had to add `#include <cstdint>` to get it to compile. The reason it does what it does is that `get_neighbor_count` never returns anything other than 0. Notice `std::cout << "Here!\n";` is never hit. Take a good look at all of the signed/unsigned warnings. https://godbolt.org/z/en43ddKKz The way to figure things like this out is to step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: Tactical note: Making 2D arrays of arrays of pointers to arrays can result in surprisingly slow code. The CPU often doesn't have enough time to get up to speed before it hits another pointer to another block of data, has stop and to load that data into cache, and then start crunching data again. If the arrays are rectangular, [consider doing  something like what doug does here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301). It can be whole orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Don't manage 2D arrays like that. Make a small wrapper that manages a std::vector<std::uint8_t> (not UCHAR). In current C++ you should always try to avoid naked new/deletes.

Comment: @RetiredNinja ah, I was using https://www.onlinegdb.com/ when I wrote it and it didn't need that `#include` and wasn't showing any warnings. Guess I'll just bring it into VS to do some real testing/debugging

Comment: And yes, I'm aware of how unoptimized and malpracticed this code is, but this isn't for production. Just trying to get basic functionality working first before I worry about cache hits and misses. Eventually, this will rewritten to utilize a 1D array treated as a 2D array, but first I just wanted to verify that my CA implementation was correct (which it doesn't appear to be the case).

Comment: @RetiredNinja Okay I pulled it into VS, and it was definitely a signed/unsigned issue in the for loop of `get_neighbor_count` (`yy` and `y` being unsigned when they should've been signed)... Feel free to create an answer so I can mark it

Comment: 1st mistake is to use raw pointers. 2nd mistake is to use pointers to pointers. 3rd mistake is unfamiliarity with RAII and rule of 0/3/5. All of these can be avoided by proper use of low-hanging fruits provided by STL. Every new programmer must start with STL; let pointers to experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, I was using unsigned primitives as opposed to signed ones, and therefore the for loop in `get_neighbor_count` never gets executed, since it partially relies on negative values.

I was also using an online IDE which wasn't showing me any errors or warnings, of which there were plenty to be made aware of.

Comment: This may be a solution that gives different output but I wouldn't be confident to say it is the only issue given all the other warnings present in the code. My "answer" would be to always turn up the warnings, don't ignore them, and use a debugger so you understand what is happening in the code. For me the ignored parameters are worse than the signed/unsigned issues. That's a broken contract for all callers of the function.

Comment: Yes but a lot of this was just a side-effect of having used an online IDE which (surprisingly) didn't pick up on any of this. The warnings and errors are easy to fix once being made aware of them, but no awareness was given until I used a different IDE. But this answer does at least solve the question as to why the cells are `DEAD`

Comment: I added more context to the answer

Comment: You can add additional compile flags under the settings in onlinegdb. I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=address,undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick sketch on how you can move all your memory managment to a 2d array class. Instead of using free functions and manual memory managment using new/delete. Note C++23 will have a multidimensional index operator you can use instead of the `at` function

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

template<typename type_t>
class vector_2d_t
{
public:
    template<std::size_t rows_v, std::size_t columns_v>
    vector_2d_t(const type_t (&values)[rows_v][columns_v]) :
        vector_2d_t{ rows_v,columns_v }
    {
        std::size_t target_index{ 0ul };
        for (const auto& row : values)
        {
            for (const auto value : row)
            {
                m_data[target_index++] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    std::size_t number_of_rows() const noexcept
    {
        return m_rows;
    }

    std::size_t number_of_columns() const noexcept
    {
        return m_columns;
    }

    vector_2d_t(std::size_t rows, std::size_t columns) :
        m_rows{ rows },
        m_columns{ columns },
        m_data(rows* columns)
    {
    }

    ~vector_2d_t() = default;

    type_t& at(std::size_t row, std::size_t column) noexcept
    {
        return m_data[to_index(row, column)];
    }

    const type_t& at(std::size_t row, std::size_t column) const noexcept
    {
        return m_data[to_index(row, column)];
    }

    // C++20
    auto operator[](std::size_t row) const noexcept
    {
        assert(row < m_rows);
        return std::span<const type_t>(&m_data[row*m_columns],m_columns);
    }

    // C++20
    auto operator[](std::size_t row) noexcept
    {
        assert(row < m_rows);
        return std::span<type_t>(&m_data[row*m_columns],m_columns);
    }


private:
    inline auto to_index(std::size_t row, std::size_t column)
    {
        assert(row < m_rows);
        assert(column < m_columns);
        return (row * m_columns) + column;
    }

    std::size_t m_rows;
    std::size_t m_columns;
    std::vector<type_t> m_data;
};

int main()
{
    vector_2d_t grid{{ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} }};
    assert(grid.at(1,2) == 6);
    grid.at(1,2) = 10;
    assert(grid.at(1,2) == 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's some very clean syntactical sugar, right there! I'll have to bookmark this for future solo projects... but sadly, the one this question is for will be limited to C++20 at best due to certain limitations of Unreal Engine (see `Modern C++ Language Syntax` at https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.2/en-US/epic-cplusplus-coding-standard-for-unreal-engine/)

Comment: It is not only syntactic sugar, it allows you to check invariants (like indices out of range) but it also ensures data locality. With your allocation scheme closely related data can be scattered to totally different memory locations. Now all data is contiguous in memory much better for (cache) locality.

Comment: The code as it is is fully C++17 compatible : https://onlinegdb.com/VRbkyfQpv

Comment: There's no sugar in this code. It could provide an index operator to accept pairs of integers with a call syntax of `[{i,j}]` alongside an oveload with call syntax `[i]` for larger dimension; that would be C++11 sugar. I would also get the address of 1st element of array in ctor and construct a `span` with explicit size to avoid the explicit `target_index`; then `ranges::copy` from the span into the vector.

Comment: The generated assembly for the for loop is quite ok. For a better index syntax I added two C++20 methods returning a span so instead of `grid.at(1,2)` you can also use `grid[1][2]`