# Interfacing C++ Classes with Python; passing non-standard types to extern C

Tags: python, c++, matrix, package

Against my own best interests I have begun learning C++ in a 'learn-by-doing' method.

I'm trying to create a C++ library to be imported in Python - specifically I've implemented a Matrix class in C++ to build experience with Object orientationm, and the idea being to harness C++ speed for potentially heavy number crunching such as matrix multiplication, but being otherwise able to use the light syntax and rich package library of Python.

I'm following a (seemingly) excellent tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@torbengraebergt/c-c-and-python-class-interfacing-f45a9ee352f4), however the implemented class and processes in that example takes and returns only ints, and the 'extern "C" wrapping' function also takes and returns integers.
(their Cpp header function)

```
class myProcessor {
protected:
    int exp;
    int size;

public:
    myProcessor(int exp_in, int size_in);
    int process(double *d, int size);
};

extern "C" {
    unsigned int myProcessorInit(int exp_in, int size_in);
    int myProcessorProcess(unsigned int id, double *d, int size);
} //end extern "C"
```

For my matrix class, I have member functions which both take and return matrix class objects (e.g. matrix addition adds together two matrix objects and returns a new one), and the class constructor takes a vector (and uses a std::vector to store the actual values row by row).

So my question, before I get further into this, is it even possible to vectors and class objects into Python -> extern "C" -> C++? And if possible, is it viable? Like; on a scale of flesh wound to 'blowing my whole leg off' how bad am I shooting myself in the foot with this implementation?

I know that [vector::data](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) can generate to the actual array where a vector stores its values, could that be used here?
I've also made a version of my matrix setup where I cast input into a 1-D array; would this be easier to port/interface?

p.s. I know Numpy essentially already does this, but the whole point is trying to learn how to do stuff myself.

Comment: The problem with moving even modestly complex types in and out of C++ is both languages need to have a 100% agreement on how to interpret those types, and C++ doesn't even guarantee that between two C++ toolchains. For example, there are several good ways to implement `std::string` that are compliant with the Standard, and they're pretty much all used. When the agreement does not line up 100% you get the whole spectrum of leg-damage.

Comment: The Python API is entirely unaware of anything C++. I think it would be a better idea to implement an actual Python module instead of messing with the FFI interface.

Comment: To expose custom classes, and/or standard library containers, you can use https://github.com/pybind/pybind11 . Not sure why would you use `extern C` .

Comment: `vector::data` can be used to move data outside C++ so long as the contents of the array are primitive, the `vector`'s lifetime is guaranteed to exceed the use of the pointer `data` returns, and nothing (like a resize triggered by `push_back`) invalidates the array that's being pointed at.

Comment: For now I'm only planning on having the matrix hold 'double' type values.

Any how, as for implementing "an actual Python module" do you mean to just code the matrix class in Python? I can do that easily, but since C-family languages are so much faster, I would love to export all the actual "number crunching" to C++. I may be overcomplicating this for myself of course - call it a newbie mistake or an idiot mistake, as you please.

Comment: Start with the Python version, assuming you haven't already, and then get some baseline profiling numbers. Unless you know the time you have to beat, you're going to take more missteps than are necessary. C++ is generally faster when tuned correctly, and sometimes the effort that tuning requires exceeds the value of the tuning.

Comment: True - but I'm not using this for any specific application, really. I'm making it for the sake of making it (and learning C++). (I've already made matrix calculus in Python before)

Comment: Understood. Just making sure there is no low-hanging fruit. Side note: [Here's a good, simple example of how to do a matrix in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301) that's similar to what you are discussing, so structurally, you're on the right path even though you can't share it with Python easily. [Here is an even simpler, but easier to misuse take](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301).