# How to speed up dense matrix multiplication?

Tags: c++, openmp, matrix-multiplication

I want to speed up the mutiplication blow:

[image]

And here is the code that I need to improve:

```
void multiply(int size, int **matA, int **matB, int ** matC) {
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++) {
            int t = matC[i][j];
            for(int k=0;k<size;k++) {
                t += matA[i][k] * matB[k][j];
            }
            matC[i][j] += t;
        }
    }
}
```

I have two matrices and a result matrix with size 5000x5000.
huge size of matrices may mean they can not be loaded in cache totally? Is there too many page fault in the for loop? I want to know how to speed up the multiplication, and how to organize data(use 1d array or 2D array?)

my answer code is list blow, I choose to use 1d array to simulate 2d array(use `new []` one time per matrix), but I am not sure if it is faster when using 2d array.
and I use a temp matrix to store transposed matrix of `matB` in order to avoid page fault in  for loop.
and I add AVX2 to get more performance.

which is better, using 1d array or 2d array with size 5000x5000?
and any other ideas or tips?

```
int** allocate(int rows, int cols) {
    int ** mat;
    mat = new int*[rows];
    int *temp = new int[rows*cols];
    for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        mat[i] = temp + i * cols;
    }
    return mat;
}


void multiply(int size, int **matA, int **matB, int ** matC) {
int i;
int n = size*size; // total size


// column-major order
int **transMatB = allocate(size, size);
int *transArrB = transMatB[0];

//copy transposed data, maybe many page faults here.
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        transMatB[i/size][i%size] = matB[i%size][i/size];
    }

#pragma omp parallel for
    for(i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        int *row = matA[i / size];
        int *col = transMatB[i % size];
        int temp;
#ifdef __AVX2__
        temp = multiplyAndSumArrays(row, col, size);
#else
        temp = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k ++) {
            temp += row[k] * col[k];
        }
#endif
        matC[i / size][i % size] += temp;
    }
    // remove temp transposed mastrix
    delete[] transMatB[0];
    delete[] transMatB; transMatB = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a library that implements matrix multiplication? This is reinventing the wheel. Fast matrix multiplication has been studied extensively.

Comment: @idmean because it is a course and I am studying it.

Comment: The first thing to do is store the data better. An array of pointers to arrays typically requires the CPU to spend a lot more time chasing down pointers and loading the data at the pointer into cache that it otherwise would have to. But if you have a pointer to a 1D array and perform the indexing math yourself, the processor can easily read ahead and cache data before it's needed for computations. Depending on the shape of the matrix 1 D array could give order of magnitude performance improvements. [See this answer from doug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301) for a an example.

Comment: The next thing to do is trust the compiler. Jack up the optimization level and let it go to work. Often the simplest, easiest to understand code can be transformed dramatically and outperform complex, hand-crafted optimizations. Start with simple code and see what the compiler can do for you and profile. This gives you a baseline against which you can compare your improvements to make sure they really are improvements.

Comment: Be careful with threading. Often the cost of creating and managing threads and synchronizing the data exceeds the benefits of performing work simultaneously. You definitely want to have baseline profiles to compare against and an algorithm that minimizes the need for synchronization before throwing threads at a problem.

Comment: If you haven't read up on the General Matrix Multiplication (GeMM) algorithm I suggest you start there.  Nvidia has a pretty good writeup on it as it relates to the GPU.  Also look at various BLAS implementations to see how they do it.

Comment: I strongly suggest you also benchmark all your implementation, so you can quantify the impact of your improvements, if any.

Comment: What is your CPU ?

Comment: _I am not sure if it is faster_ - if you don't have reproducible benchmarks, everything else is speculation and wishful thinking. If you _ever_ ask yourself "which is faster?" you should measure it. By all means ask questions about your results, or about the benchmarking itself, but get used to measuring first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix-matrix multiplication is probably the most studied kernel when it comes to optimization. For the ultimate, read the paper by Goto and van de Geijn, citation below.

The crux is that

1. this algorithm has n^3 operations on n^2 data so it has potential for data reuse in caches.
2. the simple 3-loop version has no re-use so you need to do something.
3. fortunately, all the output components are independent and so you can do major shuffling of the operations, for instance by loop interchanges.

Specifically to that last point: in a nutshell, each of the 3 loops needs to be split into two loops, one over blocks, and one in blocks. And then you have 6 loops (meaning 5! different loop orderings or so) and the 3 blocksizes as tuning parameters. The above paper analyzes this completely.

Note that this is not simple! For a reasonably do-able solution, do a recursive 2x2 multiplication: divide each matrix as a 2x2 block structure, and multiply those blocks recursively. You stop the recursion when the blocks are small enough to fit in cache.

That should be doable as a class assignment giving a nice performance improvement. (Though not as high as the Goto algorithm!) You can even simply multi-thread this.

```
Goto, Kazushige / Geijn, Robert A. van de 
Anatomy of high-performance matrix multiplication 
2008 

ACM Trans. Math. Softw. , Vol. 34, No. 3 
ACM: New York, NY, USA p. 1-25
```

Comment: is the paper the 2014 *Anatomy of High-Performance Many-Threaded
Matrix Multiplication* or another ?

Comment: @Soleil I've added the reference. It's their 2008 paper which gives a single core analysis. All the later papers build on that.