# Dynamic 2D arrays into vector C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am wondering is it possible to insert 2D dynamic array into vector in c++. If it is possible then how can I implement it? I've been trying to do it but it keeps showing me wrong results, looks like memory issue when trying to put array into vector because before that, values in array are showed correctly.

Can you show me the example how to do it?
EDIT:

The code is spread in few files but here are the necessary lines

Vector declaration:`vector<double**> vectordx;`

Array declaration:

```
 Element valXY; 
    valXY.dx= new double*[4];
      valXY.dy= new double*[4];
       for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
       {
           valXY.dx[i]= new double [4];
           valXY.dy[i]= new double [4];
       }
```

Array filling example:

```
for(int t=0; t<9; t++)
{ 
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
       {
           for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
           {
               valXY.dx[i][j]= 1;
               valXY.dy[i][j] =1;
           }
      }
wektordx.push_back(valXY.dx);
}
```

structure "Element":

```
struct Element
{
   double **dx;
   double **dy;
};
```

Comment: 1) Let's see your code. 2) `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>`, and that is a slow approach, but would still work.  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Dynamics here or is that just a wild tag guess?

Comment: `vectorization` probably doesn't apply to the question either. Read the information for a tag before you use it the first time. It keeps the site cleaner and easier to navigate and doesn't attract eyes that may not have any interest in what you're asking.

Comment: _"I've been trying to do it but it keeps showing me wrong results"_ -- always show your code! Even if it doesn't work at all, it gives a much clearer idea of what you're trying to do. When you attempt to describe it in a short paragraph, most of your intent is lost in translation. There are also many possible solutions. If you want a solution that's closest to what you imagined, then we need to see exactly what you imagined.

Comment: We absolutely must see how you are implementing your 2D array. Do it wrong and putting it in a `vector` is fatal  (See [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)). Use a compiler with [VLA  support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/4581301) and you'll find it's impossible. Use raw pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays and you're asking for a memory-management headache. We cannot offer suggestions or answers until we know how you are or are not trying to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: OK. You're using the nightmarishly horrible way that minimizes performance while maximizing programmer effort and risk of leak. Don't do this unless someone has a gun to your head. And even then it may be preferrable to take the bullet. As an alternative, take a look [at what doug does here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301). You can put `Array2D` into a `vector` and it will manage itself. The data is a contiguous block, so all but the simplest CPUs can ruthlessly exploit cache. There will be a performance hit copying it into a `vector`, so prefer `emplace`ing or moving it.

Comment: _I am wondering is it possible to insert 2D dynamic array into vector in c++._ Please clarify. Are you asking whether it is possible to have a vector with an element type of of "2D dynamic array"? How about: `using Array2D = std::vector<std::vector<double>>; std::vector<Array2D>;` Careful examination will reveal this to be the solution suggested by @PaulMcKenzie in the very first comment above. Another tack would be to try to do something with C++23's `std::mdspan`.