# How can I make this code for finding a string in a matrix work faster, e.g. in linear time?

Tags: c++, matrix

In this problem I have to count how many happy faces are in the matrix. A happy face stands for:  `:-)`. Each character of the happy face has to be in a different row in increasing order and in a different column in increasing order too.

So for example the matrix:

```
7 4
:-)-
\-::-
)-)-
)-::
\--))
::))
)---
```

The answer is 10.

I have tried this solution using lots of `for` loops. The solution is correct, but it's too slow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
typedef vector< vector<char> >Matriu;

int numberSubsequences(const Matriu &m){
int row=m.size();
int column=m[0].size();
int counter=0;


for(int i=0; i<row; ++i){
    for(int j=0; j<column; ++j){
    if(m[i][j]==':'){
        for(int i2=i+1; i2<row; ++i2){
            for(int j2=j+1; j2<column;++j2){
                if(m[i2][j2]=='-'){
                    for(int i3=i2+1; i3<row; ++i3){
                        for(int j3=j2+1; j3<column; ++j3){
                            if(m[i3][j3]==')'){
                                ++counter;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
    return counter;
    }



int main(){
    int r, c;
    while(cin >> r >> c){
        Matriu m(r,vector<char>(c));
        for(int i=0; i<r; ++i){
            for(int j=0; j<c; ++j){
                cin >> m[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << numberSubsequences(m) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't help much compared to the brute-force algorithm used, but `typedef vector< vector<char> >Matriu;` is slow. Terribly slow for a small matrix. See [what doug does here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301) for a faster approach

Comment: In your example matrix, I assume the 7 and 4 are rows and columns.  But what are the two rogue backslashes all about?

Answer (score 0):

First, find all places where your matrix contains the last character, `)`. The result is a matrix of 0 and 1. Then, calculate the cumulative sum of this matrix — for each position, how many `)` characters there are below and to the right.

Code for calculating cumulative sum:

```
// Accumulate along rows
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    for (int j = columns - 2; j >= 0; --j)
        tmp_mat[i][j] += tmp_mat[i][j + 1];

// Accumulate along columns
for (int i = rows - 2; i >= 0; --i)
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
        tmp_mat[i][j] += tmp_mat[i + 1][j];
```

Next step: find all places where your matrix contains the next-to-last character, `-`. The result is a matrix of 0 and 1. Multiply these by the cumulative sums found earlier. Then calculate the cumulative sum on the result. The cumulative sum says, for each position, how many strings `-)` there are below and to the right.

Final step: do the same for the first character, `:`. You only need to calculate one sum — over the whole matrix — no need to calculate cumulative sum here, because it's the end.

These calculations require nested loops of depth 2 — complexity O(xy) instead of O((xy)<sup>3</sup>).

---

Example: looking for `abc` in the following matrix:

```
aaabc
ababa
bbbcc
```

Step 1: find `c`

```
00001
00000
00011
```

Step 2: cumulative sum in rows, then cumulative sum in columns

```
11111            33332
00000    then    22221
22221            22221
```

Step 3: find `b`, then multiply by the cumulative sum

```
00010            00010
01010    then    02010
11100            00000
```

Step 4: cumulative sum in rows, then cumulative sum in columns

```
11110            44220
33110    then    33110
00000            00000
```

Step 5: find `a`, then multiply by the cumulative sum

```
11100            31100
10101    then    00000
00000            00000
```

Step 6: sum

```
5
```

Note that when multiplying by cumulative sum, we have to take elements at appropriate indices. In the diagram below, we multiply X by Y.

```
*****    *****
*X***    *****
*****    **Y**
```

Element Y is shifted by 1 below and to the right of X because of the constraint on the strings - the indices of string elements should advance at least by 1. If we were allowed to find strings which occupy adjacent positions in a row or column, we would multiply elements of the matrix without shift.

Comment: This answer is missing out details about how the part "*for each position, how many `)` characters there are below and to the right*" has `O(xy)` complexity. Without any code to prove it otherwise, I would say this sentence describes **nested loops** where the "*for each position*" loop is `O(xy)` and the "*below and to the right*" loop is `O(xy)` too, i.e. `O((xy)²)` in total.

Comment: Added more details

Comment: @Atmo is incorrect. By "nested loops" they are talking about looping over each column for each row. This approach is known as memoization and is a _dynamic programming_ technique. It can be done efficiently without excessive storage using a single pass over the matrix (technically 3 simultaneous passes) plus an additional array of counts enough for a single row. Here is a [demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/MWGPWzfGz). It's not the best memory access pattern, but anything more efficient would probably be a bit convoluted.

Comment: @paddy, you misunderstood what I meant. My comment was based on a previous version of the answer where all there was to read was sentences in plain English. And BTW, all I said was that it was missing details because it looked, from only that text, like it would not be `O(xy)`. But the code snippet and step-by-step description now makes it more clear.