# type "int(*)[3]" is incompatible with parameter of type "ïnt(*)[50}"

Tags: c++, function

How should I fix the code bellow, so my `GetSumOfElementsFromTheMainDiagonal` method works with different square matrices sizes?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 50;

int GetSumOfElementsFromTheMainDiagonal(int a[][MAX_SIZE], int n)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += a[i][i];
    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    

int a[3][3] = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {2, 3, 5},
    {7, 7, 7}
};

cout << GetSumOfElementsFromTheMainDiagonal(a, 3) << endl;
}
```

The error is the following:

> argument of type "int(*)[3]" is incompatible with parameter of type "ïnt(*)[50}"

Why is this so? As far as I understand, it's trying to convert `int(*)[3]` to `ïnt(*)[50}` which is clearly not possible, but how can I fix this?

I'd like the function to work for arbitrary sizes of the square matrix `a` which is `nxn`.

Comment: I would implement a Matrix class that had fields for the number of rows and columns. Raw C-style arrays like you're using are not going to be compatible across each other.

Comment: `const int MAX_SIZE = 3;` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, well, this is obviously a problem as the function would work only for matrices 3x3.

Comment: Your function is only accepting `n x MAX_SIZE`, thats not a cause of using the right value for the size. Perhaps edit the question to clarify that you want arbitrary size, because only fixing the error does not achieve that

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I apologise! Yes, I'd like the method to work with arbitrary nxn matrices.

Comment: For arbitrary square size, use `int* arr, int x` parameters and access with `arr[row * x + col]`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, and how should I invoke the function? `GetSumOfElementsFromTheMainDiagonal(&arr, 3);` doesn't work.

Comment: Just `(arr, 3)`

Comment: The function signature also need to be modified to take a `int*`. Or just use Eigen.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, then it says `type int(*)[3] is incompatible with parameter of type int *`

Comment: `(&arr[0][0], 3)` then.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, it seems to work that way, thanks!

Comment: i have to apologize. Already in the first version of the question you asked how to make it work for different sizes, I was inattentive

Comment: You can do it with a template function, but unfortunately I don't have time to write an answer right now.

Answer (score 4):

Some background:

C arrays are stored **row-major** in memory.

A 2 x 3 array `int a[2][3]` consists of 2 consecutive rows of 3 columns each.

```c
+-------+
| 0 1 2 |
| 3 4 5 |
+-------+
```

It is laid out consecutively in ascending memory addresses as follows:
`{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }`,
and can accessed like this: `{ { a[0][0], a[0][1]} a[0][2] }, { a[1][0], a[1][1], a[1][2] } }`

---

When passing an array to a function in C or C++,
it will [*decay*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-conversion-aka-decay) to a pointer.
In case of multidimensional arrays, this *decay* only affects the
outermost dimension. So the `a` in `void foo(int a[2][3])`
will decay to `int (*)[3]`, aka a pointer to an arbitrary amount of arrays of 3 elements.

```c
              +-------+
int (*)[3] -> | 0 1 2 |
              | 3 4 5 |
              +-------+
```

Using this pointer still works correctly because for `int (*a)[3]`,
calling `a[1]` will calculate the offset of the second (index 1) array of three elements, meaning that `a[1][2]` still works as if the array was passed by value (you get 5).

That is why it's **good** hat the the compiler prevented a type conversion from `int(*)[3]` to `int (*)[50]`. These types simply don't behave the same way.
Calling `a[1][0]` on the `int (*)[50]` type would access 50 memory words after the beginning of our array, which only has 6 words. A classic buffer overflow.

---

One way of fixing this would be to do the indexing yourself using a helper function:

```c
int* get(int* array, int rows, int cols, int row, int col) {
    return &array[cols * row + col];
}
```

This could be used in your code as follows:

```
int GetSumOfElementsFromTheMainDiagonal(int* array, int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += *get(array, n, n, i, i);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int a[3 * 3] = {
        1, 2, 3,
        2, 3, 5,
        7, 7, 7
    };
    std::cout << GetSumOfElementsFromTheMainDiagonal(a, 3) << '\n';
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/oWGbdPvhz

Answer (score 2):

Don't use raw c-arrays. They are confusing to work with. 2D c arrays are confusing. `std::array` is nothing but a c-array, but wrapped in a class type, and just that fixes already many quirks. For example you can pass it to functions without decaying to a pointer.

Then, if you want the function to work with `NxN` matrices without fixing `N` you can make it a function template.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <size_t N> 
struct my_matrix {
    std::array<std::array<int,N>,N> data;
    my_matrix(std::array<std::array<int,N>,N> data) : data(data) {}
    auto& operator[](size_t i) { return data[i];}
    const auto& operator[](size_t i) const { return data[i];}
    size_t size() const { return N;}
};

template <size_t N>
int GetSumOfElementsFromTheMainDiagonal(my_matrix<N>& a)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0;i < a.size();++i)
    {
        sum += a[i][i];
    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    

my_matrix<3> a = {{{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {2, 3, 5},
    {7, 7, 7}}}
};

std::cout << GetSumOfElementsFromTheMainDiagonal(a) << std::endl;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/MnoTh9Moh):

```
11
```

Note how I didn't have to change much about your function by providing a `operator[]` and `size()`. Same would have worked without `my_matrix` but using `std::array<std::array<int,N>,N>` directly, but I suppose you will want to add more members. If not you can use

```
template <size_t N>
using my_matrix = std::array<std::array<int,N,N>;
```

Either way, you do not need to pass `n` seperately.

Alternatively you can use a flat 1D array and use index transformations to use it as if it was 2D.

Comment: And if you find yourself needing matrixes with dimensions defined at runtime by user input or what-not, consider using something like [what doug does in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301).