# Conway's Game of life assymetric array issue

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays, conways-game-of-life

Recently I have been making Conway's Game of Life in c++. When I was finishing GUI of the game in Qt, I realised that I'm not able to make assymetric array (I mean number of rows != number of cols). When I try, program closes immediately with error of getting out of the array. Interesting is fact that if I set dimensions of array in my Board class (backend), row = 15 and cols = 15 and I try to increase number of cols in GUI- nothing happens, but if I increase number of rows and it cross 15- program crashes (if number of rows < 15, nothing happens).

With that knowledge, I came back to backend classes which i wrote few months ago and started setting different combinations of number of rows and cols printing it in cmd. I discovered that if i set number of rows bigger than number of cols, my function

```
check_index(int x,int y)
```

display error of indexing, BUT program for some reasons works correctly. If i set number of rows smaller than number of cols, program will compile but display nothing.

**Class Board.h:**

```
class Board
{
private:

    int m_height;
    int m_width;
    bool** m_gameboard;
    bool** m_temp_gameboard;
    bool check_index(int x, int y)const
    {
        if (x >= 0 && x < m_width && y >= 0 && y < m_height) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    void allocate_gameboard(int width, int height)
    {
        if (m_gameboard == nullptr)
        {
            m_gameboard = new bool* [width];
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
                m_gameboard[i] = new bool[height];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m_width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m_height; j++)
                m_gameboard[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    void allocate_temp_gameboard(int width, int height)
    {
        if (m_temp_gameboard == nullptr)
        {
            m_temp_gameboard = new bool* [width];
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
                m_temp_gameboard[i] = new bool[height];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m_width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m_height; j++)
                m_temp_gameboard[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    void deallocate_gameboard()
    {
        if (m_gameboard != nullptr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m_width; i++)
                delete[] m_gameboard[i];

            delete[] m_gameboard;
        }
    }

    void deallocate_temp_gameboad()
    {
        if (m_temp_gameboard != nullptr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m_width; i++)
                delete[] m_temp_gameboard[i];

            delete[] m_temp_gameboard;
        }
    }
public:

    Board(int, int);
    Board();
    void set_random() const;
    void print_gameboard() const;
    void print_temp_gameboard() const;
    void add_cell(int, int);
    void temp_add_cell(int, int);
    void remove_cell(int, int);
    void temp_remove_cell(int, int);
    void copy_GameBoard_to_Temp();
    void copy_Temp_to_Gameboard();
    void reset_array(char);
    int check_neighborhood(int, int);
    int GetHeight();
    int GetWidth();
    bool** GetGameBoard();
    ~Board();
};
```

**Board.cpp:**

Constructors:

```
Board::Board(int height, int width) : m_width(width), m_height(height)
{
    allocate_gameboard(width, height);
    allocate_temp_gameboard(width, height);
}

Board::Board()
{
    m_width = 10;
    m_height = 10;
    allocate_gameboard(m_width, m_height);
    allocate_temp_gameboard(m_width, m_height);
}
```

adding and removing functions:

```
void Board::add_cell(int x, int y)
{
    if (check_index(x, y)) m_gameboard[x][y] = true;
    else std::cout << "Add_cell:\t invalid cell index\t x: " << x << " y: " << y << std::endl;
}

void Board::temp_add_cell(int x, int y)
{
    if (check_index(x, y)) m_temp_gameboard[x][y] = true;
    else std::cout << "Add_temp_cell:\t invalid cell index\t x: " << x << " y: " << y << std::endl;
}

void Board::remove_cell(int x, int y)
{
    if (check_index(x, y)) m_gameboard[x][y] = false;
    else std::cout << "remove_cell:\t invalid cell index\t x: " << x << " y: " << y << std::endl;
}

void Board::temp_remove_cell(int x, int y)
{
    if (check_index(x, y)) m_temp_gameboard[x][y] = false;
    else std::cout << "remove_temp_cell:\t invalid cell index\t x: " << x << " y: " << y << std::endl;
}
```

check_neighborhood function:

```
int Board::check_neighborhood(int x, int y)
{
    if (check_index(x, y) == true)
    {
        int counter_of_true_states = 0;
        for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
            {
                if (check_index(x + i, y + j) == true)
                {
                    if (m_gameboard[x + i][y + j] == true and (j or i) != 0) counter_of_true_states++;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
        return counter_of_true_states;
    }
}
```

**Class GameController.cpp:**

NextGeneration fnction:

```
void GameController::NextGeneration()
{
    m_GameBoard.copy_GameBoard_to_Temp();
    bool** active_states_detector = m_GameBoard.GetGameBoard();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_GameBoard.GetHeight(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_GameBoard.GetWidth(); j++)
        {
            if (active_states_detector[i][j] == true)
            {
                if (m_GameBoard.check_neighborhood(i, j) != 3 and m_GameBoard.check_neighborhood(i, j) != 2)
                    m_GameBoard.temp_remove_cell(i, j);
            }
            else if (active_states_detector[i][j] == false)
            {
                if (m_GameBoard.check_neighborhood(i, j) == 3)
                    m_GameBoard.temp_add_cell(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    m_GameBoard.print_temp_gameboard();
    m_GameBoard.reset_array('G');
    m_GameBoard.copy_Temp_to_Gameboard();
    m_GameBoard.reset_array('T');
    std::cout << std::endl << "=====================" << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's not too late, replace `bool** m_gameboard;` with a nice `vector` of `vector`s . I'd normally recommend something more like what [doug does here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301) but `vector<bool>` [gets weird enough to need its own documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). You'd probably have to switch to `vector`s of `uint8_t` or `std::byte`s to use doug's approach.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < m_GameBoard.GetHeight(); i++) { for (int j = 0; j < m_GameBoard.GetWidth(); j++) active_states_detector[i][j]` Everywhere else, the first index is limited by width, and the second by height. But here you use them the wrong way round.

Comment: When you do switch to a vector you should also switch to using `.at(index)` instead of `[index]` so it will throw an exception when you have an out of range access and you can examine why in the debugger. It looks like you may have rows and columns backwards in at least one place.

Comment: _Side note:_ Functions `allocate_gameboard` and `allocate_temp_gameboard` will both leak memory if a `std::bad_alloc` is thrown after a previous call to operator `new` was successful.