Efficient method to initialize a really large C++ vector with the same values
I was doing this leetcode problem and I had to initialize a very large 2D DP array of size 2^14 x 14 with all entries set to -1 to solve the problem. However I noticed a big performance difference depending on whether I'm using vector or array for this DP array.
Using vector:
vector<vector<int>> dp(1 << nums.size(), vector<int>(nums.size(), -1));

gave me a runtime of 251 ms
Meanwhile, using array with memset:
int dp[1 << 14][14];
memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));

only gave me a runtime of 95 ms
Is there a way to initialize this array as efficiently using C++ vector?
I have tried alternatives such as using std:fill, but it doesn't produce any runtime difference.

dont use 2d vectors, instead write a class that holds a 1d vector and pretend that it is 2d using maths

Simple example of above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301 Rational: One vector is contiguous and cache-friendly. A vector of vectors is exactly that: One vector that holds a bunch of other vectors all with their own block of memory that might not be anywhere near the others.

That's surprisingly close given fact that each vector must allocate memory by new (technically malloc), and then copy that provided sub vector into it.

It's worth considering if this is actually the expected solution to the problem.

Why do you want to use std::vector here?  There might be a good reason, but what it is will govern the solution.

It's not needed in this case, but it did make me wonder if it's possible to do the thing I asked in case I'm faced with a problem that needs it

@NathanOliver I curious that why don't recommend to use 2d vectors... performance or complexity concerns... or something else?...

@SheltonLiu Its a performance issue.  A 2d vector, unlike a 2d array, does not guarantee that all the rows will be in one contiguous piece of memory.  Each row itself is guaranteed to be contiguous, but row 1 could be in a completely different place in memory than row 2, and so on.  This means every time you change rows you there's a good chance you'll get a cache miss

Using something like this:
template <class T>
class matrix2d {
    std::vector<T> data;
    std::size_t cols;
    std::size_t rows;
public:
    matrix2d(std::size_t y, std::size_t x, T init = T()) : cols(x), rows(y), data(x*y, init) {}

    T &operator()(std::size_t y, std::size_t x) { 
        assert(x<=cols);
        assert(y<=rows);
        return data[y*cols+x];
    }
    T operator()(std::size_t y, std::size_t x) const {
        assert(x<=cols);
        assert(y<=rows);
        return data[y*cols+x];
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, matrix2d const &m) {
        for (std::size_t y=0; y<m.rows; y++) {
            for (std::size_t x = 0; x<m.cols; x++) {
                os << m(y,x) << "\t";
            }
            os << "\n";
        }
        return os;
    }
};


int main() { 
  using namespace std::chrono;
  
  auto start = steady_clock::now();
  matrix2d m(1<<14, 14, -1);
  auto stop = steady_clock::now();

  uint64_t total = 0;

  for (int i=0; i<(1<<14); i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<14; j++) {
        total+=m(i,j);
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Total: " << total << "\n";
  std::cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(stop-start).count() << "us\n";

    auto start2 = steady_clock::now();   
    int dp[1 << 14][14];
    memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
    auto stop2 = steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(stop2-start2).count() << "us\n";
}

I get about the same amount of time to initialize one as the other (but both are in the range of hundreds of microseconds, not anything like multiple milliseconds.
